# Django REST Framework + Django REST Swagger

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

Having a hard time configuring Swagger UI Here are the very explanatory docs in - https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. My settings.py looks like this.

[image]

urls.py looks like this.

[image]

But the swagger web page isn't loading properly.

[image]

and the console log is as follows.

[image]

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django-rest-swagger schema documentation](http://marcgibbons.github.io/django-rest-swagger/schema/), there is some code examples there about how this ties into DRF. You can read some more about this by visiting the [DRF Schema Generator](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#schemagenerator) documentation.

If you just want to get up and running without learning more about the library, this [article](http://hirelofty.com/blog/auto-generate-swagger-docs-your-django-api/) does a good job about showing project architecture and integrating DRS with DRF.

Comment: You don't even have rest_framework in the `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

very first, install django rest framework into your application and import that in setting.py file

make few APIs using DRF and then add swagger setting inside your setting.py file

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
   'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
    'api_key': {
        'type': 'apiKey',
        'in': 'header',
        'name': 'Authorization'
    }
},  # setting to pass token in header
'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
# set to True if session based authentication needed
'JSON_EDITOR': True,
'api_path': 'api/',
'api_version': 'v0',

"is_authenticated": False,  # Set to True to enforce user authentication,
"is_superuser": False,  # Set to True to enforce admin only access
'unauthenticated_user': 'django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser',
# unauthenticated user will be shown as Anonymous user in swagger UI.
```

}

Note:- You can edit the swagger setting according to you need.